# Action button in view for deleting specified rows

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

Is there any Lotus formula which can be used on an action in a view , for deleting / erasing some specified view' rows? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a button that uses the Simple Action called Delete from database. It will delete selected documents.